# Height li element to change variable

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the value based on the height of a li - element.
The element is shown based on a value from our database which can't use here.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<li id="ul_customer1"> 
  <a href="" ng-click="menu('pages/1.html')"  id="menu-1" class="editable nav-label">Achtergronddata</a>
</li>
```

And my Javascript code:

```
if($("ul_customer1").actual("height") > 5) { 
  var customer= 1;
} else {
  var customer= 0;
}
```

When active the height of the li = 129. When hidden it is 4.

I also tried "visible" and "css display block", but those don't work.

How can I change var customer based on the height of the li element?

Thanks,

Isabelle

Comment: Is this an angularjs app? If so you should write this kind of code in a directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `outerHeight()` or `height()` functions:

```
if ($("#ul_customer1").height() > 5) { 
  var customer = 1;
} else {
  var customer = 0;
}
```

And make sure you give `#` for `id`.

Here's a demo for you:

*When there's nothing inside `#ul_customer1`...*

```js
$(function () {
  if ($("#ul_customer1").height() > 5) { 
    var customer = 1;
  } else {
    var customer = 0;
  }
  alert(customer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ul_customer1"></div>
```

*When there's something inside `#ul_customer1`...*

```js
$(function () {
  if ($("#ul_customer1").height() > 5) { 
    var customer = 1;
  } else {
    var customer = 0;
  }
  alert(customer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ul_customer1">Hello<br />Hi</div>
```

> ***Note:*** This looks like a X-Y Problem to me. I believe you are checking if the particular element is empty or not. If that was the case, use `:is(empty)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunatly it doesn't work. Any other ideas?